# Hide a "li" tag via button click using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

My code is below:

```
 <ul class="classul">  
 <?php
    $uid = $_REQUEST['uid'];
    include("lib/db_function.php"); 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tblproject";
    $exc = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
    while($val = mysql_fetch_array($exc)){
?>                  
    <li id="li<?php echo $val['projectId']?>"><a href="#<?php echo $val['projectId']?>"><?php echo $val['projectName']?></a></li>

   <?php } ?> 
    <li><img src="images/Plus-icon.png" width="30" height="30" id="addproject"></li> 
   <input type="hidden" name="uidhide" id="uidhide" value="<?php echo $uid;?>">
</ul> 



    <?php   
$qry ="SELECT * FROM tblproject";
    $re = mysql_query($qry) or die (mysql_error());
    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($re)){
?>  
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var ul = $('.classul li').addClass('<?php echo $data['projectId'];?>');
            $("#hideproject<?php echo $data['projectId'];?>").click(function(e) {
                ul.remove();


            });
});
   </script>
 <input type="button" name="hideproject" id="hideproject<?php echo $data['projectId'];?>" value="Hide Project">
<?php 
}
?>
```

**Problem:** when I click on button Hide Project it will hide all `li tag`

**What I need:** when I click on button Hide Project I want to hide only one `li tag` with it own id that I generate it in `php`.

Comment: Please don't confuse [tag:php] with [tag:html], showing the former doesn't help when we need to see the latter (jQuery, and JavaScript in general) works client-side with rendered HTML. Can you show an example of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
//ul.remove();
$("#li"+<?php echo $data['projectId'];?>).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var ul = $('.classul li').addClass('<?php echo $data['projectId'];?>');
            $("#hideproject<?php echo $data['projectId'];?>").click(function(e) {
                ul.remove();
$(this).addClass('.classul'); // add this line


            });
});
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'ul' variables holds the full ul list (i.e. all li elements ) because of

```
$('.classul li')
```

returns all the li. when you call .remove, it has all li removed.

With minimal change, you can try changing the above code into

```
$('.classul li#'<?php echo $data['projectId']; ?>)
```

Besides, looping database query result set to generate HTML code is bad, looping to generate Javascript code mixed with PHP code is worse if not the worst.